# Which is the difference between these polymorphic types?

Tags: lambda, polymorphism, system-f

In System F, what is the difference between the following 3 types: [image: Three formulas involving forall and implies as below.]

Reproduced in text here:

```
∀X.((X → X) → (X → X))
∀X.((X → X) → ∀X.(X → X))
((∀X.X → X) → (∀X.X → X))
```

Is the second one more general than the first?

Comment: Downvote wasn't me, but I think you should ask that on cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Me neither, but CS might be more suitable -- this is not about Haskell. Also, I'd start from alpha-converting those quantifiers ...

Comment: Do you mean that after forall I sould  replace a with b?

Comment: Belongs to cs.se, but probably even they would want a clearer question with what you understand and what not: instead of just "solve this for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how tight `forall` quantifier binds. Lets assume that it binds on next terminal expression (variable or `()`-block).

The first will become `(X0 -> X0) -> (X0 -> X0)` where `X0` is a fresh type variable.

The second will become `(X0 -> X0) -> forall X1. (X1 -> X1)` where `X0` and `X1` are fresh.

The third - `(bot -> X) -> (bot -> X)` where `X` is the old binding and bot is the uninhabited `forall X. X`.